# How to use a trained recurrent Neural Network in matlab

Tags: matlab, recurrent-neural-network

I have trained a RNN in matlab.

I have an input matrix say *X* and I need the outputs for that. but in order to use the net, always the output vector is also required! even for onestep ahead net without loop. 
I tried to feed the one-step ahead by creating a loop and build an input vector in each time-step  by combining X(t) and the output of RNN for the previous time-step.

```
Xi=0;                    % Initial output for one-timestep
for j=1:size(X,2)
  input={X(:,j);Xi};     % It is like using function    
  ys = nets(input);      % get the output of RNN   
  y(end+1)=cell2mat(ys); % convert it to mat and save it
  Xi=cell2mat(ys);       % save the last output for next input
end
```

But the performance is **very low** so something is wrong.

**what is the solution?**

Comment: What does "performance is very low" mean?

Comment: When i even input the train data, the error is very high. Completely different from the targets.